# Can outlook web add-in entry page(taskpaneurl) know which task pane button triggers the visit?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

My add-in has multiple drop down items when you click the add-in button.

All of them will navigate you to the same log-in page.

But after log in, the app needs to know to which subsequent page the user need to be redirected to.

For example, when I click the "play" button in the drop down, after log in I will be redirected to the play.html. And "study" will be to the study.html.

If the log in page(taskpaneurl) has no such knowledge, I need to have multiple log in page tided to different subsequent pages.
[image: example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The add-in platform doesn't provide an API for this, but you can do this by providing a query string in your url.